# CSS isn't responding

Tags: html, css, debugging

My CSS page has stopped responding. I checked for typos & can't see what might be wrong.

I'm guessing there is an error with the CSS file as I don't see anything wrong with the HTML file (have checked for typos & syntax errors) but I am very new to this and don't see what is wrong with it.

I have even tried deleting the content in the CSS page altogether and it doesn't change anything.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(209, 213, 228);
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    margin: 0%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.container header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}

.container .form {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.form .input-box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-box label {
    color: #333;
}

.form :where(.input-box input, .select-box, ) {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #707070;
    margin-top: px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/*
.form .column {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 15px;
}
this makes the input boxes go side by side instead of below one another*/

/*
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
    word-break: break-word;
}

.column1 {
    width: 15%;
}

.signal {
    width: 25%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2.5px; /* padding was affecting boxes on page in ios preview, smaller padding allowed it to fit 
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%%;
    background-color: #dddddd;  
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 30%;
    
} */

input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #707070;
    margin-top: px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.3);
}

.outline {
    border: 2px solid #333;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
}


.select-box select {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #none;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    outline: none;
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #e2d847;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #e2d847;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

.select-box select:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #e2d847;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #e4c749;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .form .column {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}


/*THIS HELPS WRAP CONTENT INSIDE OF IOS SCREEN - HAD ISSUE WITH COLUMNS STICKING OUT OF SCREEN SO ADDED THIS)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Shop Unit Inspection Sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/4.1.7/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header class="head">Shop Unit Service Sheet</header>
        <form action="#" class="form">

            <div class="column">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Client/Site Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Job Number</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input type="date" required />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-box">
                <label>Site Address</label>
                <input type="text" required />
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="outline">
                <h3>Device 1</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>

                <h3>Device 2</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>


                <h3>Device 3</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>

                <h3>Device 4</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>

                <h3>Device 5</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>

                <h3>Device 6</h3>

                <div class="input-box">
                    <label>Flow Switch Manufacturer, Size & Model</label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Location </label>
                        <input type="text" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label>Signal Received</label>
                        <input type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div> <br>
            </div>



            <br>
            <label>Any unprotected areas?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>All drain valves plugged?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Are there any contaminated sprinklers?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Are there any obstructed sprinklers?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Guards installed where required?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Flexible pipes to sprinkler heads installed correctly?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Damage or corrosion to pipework & fittings?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>Operation & inspection of trace heating & lagging?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>500mm from Sprinkler Heads within Sales Area?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>1000mm from Sprinkler Heads with Stock Room?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label>All valves secured?</label>
            <div class="select-box">
                <select>
                    <option hidden>Yes/No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>

            <label for="comments">Further Comments</label>
            <div class="row">
                <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: "My CSS page has stopped responding..." ... your browser may be fetching the cache of it. Try appending it with an arbitrary url param, e.g. `styles.css?t=1`. If that doesnt work, then its your style rules are being loaded but simply are not doing what you expected.

Comment: What are we looking for here? What does "stop responding" mean? Please see [ask].

Comment: The CSS has no effect what so ever. I noticed this whilst trying to add a border box which wouldn't seem to appear. But then tried deleted my entire content on CSS page and noticed this also changed nothing. So it seems it is not responding what so ever.

Comment: It's working for me. Check your css file name properly in href="style.css"